# Regexp for unicode string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the file with some text data. I need to get all interesting for me strings from this file. All interesting strings are framed with "\x01\x00\x00\x00" and "\x00". I try to use the folowing regexp to find these strings:

```
(\x01\x00\x00\x00[\u0000-\uFFFF]+\x00)
```

But it doesn't work correctly. What am I doing wrong? The full code is here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

file  = open(r"H:\1705\test.adb")
temp = file.readlines()
resString = ""
for line in temp:
    resString += line
p = re.compile(ur"(\x01\x00\x00\x00[\u0000-\uFFFF]+\x00)", re.UNICODE)
res = p.finditer(resString)
for match in res:
    print match.group()[0].decode("cp1251")
```

Comment: If it's unicode, which encoding is it? Why aren't you decoding from that encoding when opening the file? Why are you decoding from `cp1251`?

Answer (score 0):

In regex a backslash escapes special characters to suppress their special meaning, for example if you wanted to search for a dot using regex you would use `\.`.

To search for a backslash, thus, you would want to use `\\`, resulting in your searchable string being

```
\\x01\\x00\\x00
```

and so on.